# 条件によって読み込むファイルを切り替えるには

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

現在、IIS7 + ASP.NET(VB) にて、次のように記述しています。

```
<%
    if request = page1
%><!-- #INCLUDE file="page1.inc" --><%
    else if request = page2
%><!-- #INCLUDE file="page2.inc" --><%
    else
%><!-- #INCLUDE file="default.inc" --><%
    end if
%>
```

しかし、これでは一度全てのpage*.incが読み込まれるものと思っています。それはとてもナンセンスだと思います。(ifで分岐もナンセンスではありますが･･･)
例えば、Perlだと次のような記述が出来ます。

```
my $request = 'page' . $num . '.pl';
require $request;
```

(勿論上記の書き方には脆弱性があるのでそのままは使いませんが、例えば、です。)
VB.NET?にはこのように、特定のものだけを読み込むような手法はありますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET(.aspx)は初回(厳密にはアプリケーションプールのライフサイクル内での初回…だったはず)リクエスト時に自動的にコンパイルされます。(初回のレスポンスが遅いのはこのためです)
２回目以降はコンパイル済みのもので処理されるのですべてが読み込まれている必要があります。

ロジックで読み込むものを切り替える場合は、sample1.aspx, sample2.aspx,… として条件によりServer.Transfer()する事もできます。(こちらの方が各ページの管理・編集が楽かも)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ということは、スクリプト言語のように、動的に読み込むファイルを決定する、ということは出来ないのですね。
おそらく本回答が正解になるかとは思いますが、もう少しまって代案ございませんでしたらチェックをいれさせていただきます。